# Event/Observer input into database

Tags: magento

I have an event observer creating a log after an order is placed from the admin section.  How can I get this to insert into a database instead of being a log file?  Can anyone provide a good tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics/

Firstly you are going to need to add the setup/read/write sections to your config.xml. Lets say your module is Test/Demo then your setup section may look a bit like this:

```
  <models>
     <demo>
        <class>Test_demo_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>Demo_mysql4</resourceModel>
     </demo>
     <demo_mysql4>
        <class>Test_Demo_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
           <demo>
              <table>test_demo</table>
           </demo>
        </entities>
     </demo_mysql4>
  </models>
  <resources>
     <demo_setup>
        <setup>
           <module>Test_demo</module>
           <class>Test_Demo_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
           <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
     </demo_setup>
     <demo_write>
        <connection>
           <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
     </demo_write>
     <demo_read>
        <connection>
           <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
     </demo_read>
  </resources>
```

At this point we need to create initialize the model for magento to load it. 'demo/**_**' can be 'demo/whateveryouwant' as long as you keep whateveryouwant the same throughout the module. 'id' is the primary key and identifier magento uses for this model.

```
//Test/Demo/Model/Mysql4/Comment.php
class Test_Demo_Model_Mysql4_Comment extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->init('demo/________', 'id');
    {
}
```

From here you're going to need to create the database install script. This can be done by simply creating the file Test/Demo/sql/demo_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php where 0.1.0 is the version number used in your config file. It will look something like this:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup()
$installer->run("
    #your create table goes here
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

What this will do is create your table, you can use

```
CREATE TABLE {$installer ->getTable('demo/_____') as defined in your configuration file to create the table name used in the file. This will also create an entry in the table core_resource that will specify the name and version number. In order to make a modification to the table you'll need to delete the original table as well as it's entry in core_resource. At this point you'll want to create a model to manage the data. Here's an example of that for a table that looks like: 

//comment  -String
//poster   -String
//Id       -int autoincrement
public function addComment($comment, $poster)
{
    $comment = Mage::getModel('Demo/______');
    $comment->setComment($comment);
    $comment->setPoster($poster);
    $comment->save();
}
```

For column names such as poster_id you will use setPosterId. Using camel case each captial letter indicates an underscore before hand.

Poster_Id -> PosterId
posterid  -> Posterid

To get values from the database:

```
//using the same database example as above
public function getAllByPoster($poster)
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('Demo/________')->getCollection();
    $collection->addFilter('poster', $poster);
    return collection;
}
```

This will return all of the posts by a specific poster. There's one problem though, get collection hasn't been defined for this class. We have one last file to create before we can see how to display those results from getAllByPoster.

```
//Test/Demo/Model/Mysql4/Comment/Collection.php
class Test_Demo_Model_Mysql4_Comment_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('comments/comment');
    }
}
```

At this point we have everything we need to read and write to the database using magento's classes. To print a collection we simply:

```
foreach (Mage::getModel('demo/_____')->getAllByPoster($id) as $something)
```

and display the individual attributes we'd like to from those.