# Mystical "F colon" in c#

Tags: c#, syntax

I was working on refactoring some c# code with ReSharper. One of the things I've run into is a c# operator that I'm unfamiliar with.

In my code, I had this

```
Mathf.FloorToInt(NumRows/2)
```

where NumRows is an integer. ReSharper suggests that I should change it to

```
Mathf.FloorToInt(f: NumRows/2)
```

I'm pretty sure that `f:` is some flag that tells it to cast NumRows as a float but I cannot find any documentation for `f:` online. Can anyone elaborate on what exactly `f:` does or link me to a MSDN page about it?

(Although I have a good idea of what f: does, it's hard to search the internet for a colon, and I'd like to know what it does before I use it)

**Update 1:** Regardless of what I'm trying to do, I'm interested in the f-colon syntax

**Update 2:** Turns out it was actually Visual Studio suggesting that I *could* add the argument name 'f' not ReSharper, but that does't change the correct answer..

Comment: Is R# suggesting that you *should* (e.g. Warning) or that you *could* (e.g. Information/Hint)?

Comment: I updated the question, it was actually a Visual Studio tooltip and not an R#er suggestion like I thought. (too many things popping up...)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a [named parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). Look at the defintion of `Mathf.FloorToInt`, it will have a parameter named `f`.

Resharper is indicating that the code could be made more readable by using a named parameter in this case.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I didn't even stop to think that it might have been FloorToInt specific.

Comment: It is not recommended to post links containing the answer without elaborating on it, as the content of the link is subject to change and deletion.

Comment: @NathanMann, while it is correct that links may change, the given  description here ("named parameter") is enough to easily find it in Google again if it were to become invalid (just add "c#" to it and you get the info you need). Sometimes even correct answers are just short.

Comment: @NathanMann and why do you [use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507420/event-observer-input-into-database/11507841#11507841) links in your answers?...

Comment: @meze Because questions such as how do I write this module that is 200 lines of code isn't a class to be taught on here.I imagine that example you gave is about a 5-6 page article on creating what he's trying to create. I'd love to see you answer that question with a 'brief' summary of that article that can explain what he's asking.

Comment: Seems like a bug to recommend using a named parameter for a function that only has one parameter. It seems like that just makes the code harder to read. I wonder what the justification for that advice is?

Comment: @MarkBessey Once I realized it was a visual studio popup and not a ReSharper popup it makes more sense. VS wants to tell you everything you can do, regardless of context. For example, if I click on a private variable it gives me the option to make it public, protected, or internal, regardless of what that would mean. I think in this case, VS saw that the parameter had a name and offered to let me include it.

Answer (score 9):

In the C# 4.0, you can switch around the parameter expressions in method invocation.

When there is only one parameter, it does not help you much, if at all: there is no doubt about what the expression represents, if there is only one parameter. However, with multiple parameters, the feature becomes a lot more helpful: you can pair up parameter names with expressions representing their values, and pass parameters in any order that you like. Readers of your program would not need to refer to the method signature in order to understand what expression represents which parameter.

```
private static void MyMethod(int a, int b, int c) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", a, b, c);
}

public static void Main(string[] args) {
    MyMethod(1, 2, 3);
    MyMethod(c:1, a:2, b:3);
}
```

This prints

```
1 2 3
2 3 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at the [named parameter syntax](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/11/01/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-2-named-parameters.aspx).